# How do I set the height of the image in the ListTile in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

I have a List in my Flutter app in which I am trying to resize the leading image to ressemble the List as shown below. I can't however understand how to fix the aspect ratio to have the height equal to the width and make the box a square.

This is my code for the ListView:

```
Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemExtent: 100.0,
              //   padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              itemCount: filteredUsers.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ListTile(
                    leading: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)),
                      child: Image.network(
                        "https://d36tnp772eyphs.cloudfront.net/blogs/1/2018/02/Taj-Mahal.jpg",
                      ),
                    ),
                    title: Text("Taj Mahal"),
                    subtitle: Text("India"));
              },
            ),
          ),
```

This is what it looks like:
[image]

And this is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To create a square crop of the image on your ListTile, you can use the [AspectRatio](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AspectRatio-class.html) widget to define the child's aspect ratio as (1 / 1) to make a square, then set `Image.network` fit to `BoxFit.cover`.

```dart
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: 20,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 1,
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4.0)),
          child: Image.network(
            'https://d36tnp772eyphs.cloudfront.net/blogs/1/2018/02/Taj-Mahal.jpg',
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      title: Text('Title $index'),
      subtitle: Text('Subtitle $index'),
    );
  },
),
```

[image: Sample]